# According to Kiron Krishnan, the Mahabharata is not mentioned in the Vedas but the lineage Mahabharata characters are. Doesn't that make it false?

Tags: scripture, vedas, mahabharata

Kiron Krishnan from Quora claims that Dhritarashtra, Parikshit, Janamejaya and their ancestors are mentioned in the Vedas, but there is no mention of the Mahabharata characters or even the war itself. He says that this is conclusive evidence against the Mahabharata ever being historical. Can somebody refute this?

Comment: I have a friend named Indra. Yesterday he played football. But in Vedas, there is mention of Indra, but no mention of Indra playing football. So this proves that my friend didn't play football yesterday? People can keep names based on the names of sages seeing those in Vedas. Also, events of Vedas work like a blueprint for creation, so if the full Mahabharata was written, those exact events would occur in every cycle. But if partial events are mentioned at least those portions would repeat in all cycles of creation and events after it can have different outcomes based on various conditions.

Comment: Then why do Vedas mention Dasarajna war? Wouldn't such an important war have at least a mention?

Comment: Opinion based questions aren't allowed in this site as far as i know. About Kiron Krishnan, he is frustrated with purans and such scriptures which kinda insults indra. He even goes as far as to not even consider upanishads as part of vedas. His knowledge and insights on vedas are quite good but you don't need to accept all he says.